# How to build library on unix to run websocket server in c?

Tags: c, unix, libraries

I am trying to learn about websockets and was given a link to https://github.com/Theldus/wsServer where I can download and run the server. When I follow the instructions in the readme and use the given make file and then try and run the program, I get an error message because the library is not built.
I have all the files in the directory and then do make. From there to run the program I do `gcc file.c -I include/ -o file -pthread libws.a` but it says that libws.a does not exist. Im not very good with C and am not sure what I need to do to build the library. I added the Readme and make files so you can see what I am following.

Readme file

```
wsServer - a very tiny WebSocket server library written in C

###Library The library is made to be as simple as possible, so I don't follow to the letter the RFC 6455, the only thing this library can do is send and receive text messages and treats them as events.

So it could not be helpful if you facing with a big application, but if you just want to send some messages between a non serious application, help yourself, :-)

###Building The process to build is very easy, just type make to build e make clean to clear your workspace. When the library is compiled, a new file called libws.a will be generated, you just have to link this library across your main application.

###Why to complicate if things can be simple? The wsServer abstracts the idea of sockets and you only need to deal with three types of events defined:

/* New client. */
void onopen(int fd);

/* Client disconnected. */
void onclose(int fd);

/* Client sent a text message. */
void onmessage(int fd, unsigned char *msg);

/* fd is the File Descriptor returned by accepted connection. */
this is all you need to worry about, nothing to think about return values in socket, accepting connections, and so on.

As a gift, each client is treated in a separate thread, so you will not have to worry about it. ####A complete example (file.c)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ws.h>

void onopen(int fd)
{
    char *cli;
    cli = ws_getaddress(fd);
    printf("Connection opened, client: %d | addr: %s\n", fd, cli);
    free(cli);
}

void onclose(int fd)
{
    char *cli;
    cli = ws_getaddress(fd);
    printf("Connection closed, client: %d | addr: %s\n", fd, cli);
    free(cli);
}

void onmessage(int fd, unsigned char *msg)
{
    char *cli;
    cli = ws_getaddress(fd);
    printf("I receive a message: %s, from: %s/%d\n", msg, cli, fd);

    sleep(2);
    ws_sendframe(fd, "hellow");
    sleep(2);
    ws_sendframe(fd, "wassup brow");

    free(cli);
    free(msg);
}

int main()
{
    struct ws_events evs;
    evs.onopen    = &onopen;
    evs.onclose   = &onclose;
    evs.onmessage = &onmessage;
    ws_socket(&evs, 8080);

    return 0;
}
to build the example (assuming you already built the library), you just have to do something like gcc file.c -I include/ -o file -pthread libws.a
```

Makefile

```
CC=gcc
AR=ar
INCLUDE  = $(CURDIR)/include
CFLAGS   =  -Wall -Werror
CFLAGS  +=  -I $(INCLUDE) -std=c99
ARFLAGS  =  cru
LIB      =  libws.a

C_SRC = $(wildcard base64/*.c)    \
        $(wildcard handshake/*.c) \
        $(wildcard sha1/*.c)      \
        $(wildcard *.c)

OBJ = $(C_SRC:.c=.o)

all: $(OBJ)
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $(LIB) $^

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $< $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@

clean:
    @rm -f base64/*.o
    @rm -f handshake/*.o
    @rm -f sha1/*.o
    @rm -f *.o
    @rm -f $(LIB)
```

Comment: `gcc file.c -I include/ -o file -pthread ./libws.a`?

Comment: or add `-L 'path_to_lib'` to your compile line?

Comment: No neither worked

Comment: How do i find the path to the library in unix?

Comment: `man find` - use this to find your file

Comment: Did you build libws.a before you attempted to build "file.c", as directed by the README?  If you did, then "libws.a" will be in the wsServer directory, and building "file.c" can be accomplished via: `gcc file.c -I include/ -o file -pthread libws.a`

Comment: shouldnt make take care of building libws.a?

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of wsServer. You should have created an issue at the time and I could try to guide you or try to improve the README.

The suggestions in the comments above are correct you just needed to:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/Theldus/wsServer
make
```

to build the library and generate a libws.a file.

wsServer now also brings an example file in the example/ folder, so what I suggest to you is something like:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/Theldus/wsServer
cd example/
make
```

A binary file named `send_receive` will then be generated and ready for execution.

*(I know that the question is 2 years old and the OP has probably solved your problem, I am answering just for completeness)*